# Personalizar URL y abrir nueva pestaña basado en formulario

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero personalizar una URL a partir de un único dato, en este caso nombre. Al enviar abriría una nueva ventana añadiendo al final de la URL el nombre que coloqué en el input.

Por ejemplo: ingreso la palabra veterinaria y la nueva pestaña saldría   `palabras.com/veterinaria`.

Espero puedan ayudarme. Éste es mi código:

```
<form id='form'>
  <label for="nombre">Ingresar nombre:</label>
  <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre">
  <li class="button">
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
  </li>     
</form>
```

Y así se ve el formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tendrias que empezar a probar algo, y cuando te trabes mostras como vas y asi te podemos ayudar. De cero no tiene gracia. 
Lo que yo haria seria, guardar en una variable la primer parte de la url (sin el nombre personalizado) y en otra variable guardaria el nombre.Al dar click en enviar pasarian 3 cosas: Se guarda la variable del nombre, se concatena en la variable de la url y se redirecciona a esta url

Comment: debes colocar aquello que haz intentado en codigo, aunque tu duda puede ser resuelta redirigiendo al usuario por metodo GET mediante el mismo formulario hacia la misma ventana, seguro que deseas que en vez de ello se abra otra ventana?

Comment: favor de ayudarme agregué un poco de código

Comment: @GianMarco no incluyas la respuesta en tu pregunta. Basta con que la marques como aceptada (que ya hiciste). Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo utilicé este html

```
    <form id='form'>
    <label for="nombre">Ingresar nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre">
    <li class="button">
        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </li>     
    </form>
```

Añade el siguiente codigo js para redireccionar la pagina

```
$('#form').submit(function (event){
     event.preventDefault();
     let sitio = 'http://palabras.com/';
     let url = site + $('#nombre').val();
     window.location.replace(url);
});
```

EDIT:
necesitas JQuery lo puedes añadir a tu html, hay varias formas, yo personalmente para desarrollar utilizo JQuery local, en este enlace está bien explicado
https://www.tutorialesjquery.com/2019/01/17/como-insertar-jquery-en-un-proyecto/

Aquí muestran las diferentes formas de añadir un fichero JavaScript a tu html
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.hostinger.es/tutoriales/insertar-javascript-en-html/amp/

Saludos, espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Amigo utilice tu código, pero como estoy aprendiendo quisiera saber como insterto codigo JS.

Comment: el resultado sale asi http://localhost/?nombre=palabra, no hay forma de eliminar "?nombre=

Comment: Es que no tienes agregado el jquery.js al parecer, voy a editar la respuesta para que tengas toda la info dónde buscar y como añadir los scripts. pD: es amiga :D

Comment: Señorita Claudia en primer lugar me disculpo por la confusión. Así mismo muchas gracias tienes toda la razón, tenia que instalar JQUERY, te agradezco infinitamente por tu código y por las recomendaciones que diste, un saludo y cuídate mucho.

Comment: Me alegro mucho, un gusto. Saludos